# Multiview and Browser's Back button

Tags: asp.net, .net, multiview

I have a Multiview control with 4 steps. When I click the browser back button , previous step appears. I want to get rid of it and want the browser to go to previous page rather than previous step. Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hack-ish approach:  Put it inside an UpdatePanel.  (I'm assuming this is NOT asp-classic, by the way, since classic asp had no such control.  I removed that tag for you.)